# Captcha point doesn't work

Tags: captcha

Captcha works on the login form and webform, but I have a JavaScript error on the registration and the password reset forms. The registration form doesn't work.

> The resource from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js... was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

On /admin/config/people/captcha/captcha-points, I tried to disable the CAPTCHA for this form, or to delete the user_register_form CAPTCHA point, but the JavaScript error persists.

I tried to uninstall the Captcha module, but it causes this exception error.

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The 'captcha_point' entity type does not exist." at /home/mydomain/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php line 139

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It looks like the Captcha module had a bad update at some point, which was fixed by a later update: https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha/issues/3195625  Try updating to the latest version, and make sure to run the module updates within Drupal after updating.

Comment: My version is the latest:
 8.x-1.4 Team released 20 July 2022

Comment: I cannot hand over the site to the customer because registration is not possible.

Comment: If I could just make the Captcha not do anything on the registration page (don't want to load the JS - https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js) then I would buy time to find a solution for this.

Comment: Very interesting.
My site is multilingual.
On the Hungarian side, the system cannot load the JS in the registration form
On the English side, however, it works perfectly without any problems.
How do I solve this?
:)

Comment: There is a workaround for this. You have to find the burned-in setting at the SQL level, e.g. like this: 

SELECT * FROM dr_config where data like '%<lanuage specific text detail>%'; 

If the blob in this line is properly modified, the system sends out the individual registration notification. This is better than nothing, at most this section can only be modified by the developer until it becomes clear why the text template rewritten on the corresponding admin interface is not taken into account.